# Information heap size

Tags: javascript, heap-size

What information can I obtain from the `performance.memory` object in Chrome?
What do these numbers mean? (are they in kb's or characters)
What can I learn from these numbers?

Example values of `performance.memory`

```
MemoryInfo {
  jsHeapSizeLimit: 793000000,
  usedJSHeapSize: 10000000,
  totalJSHeapSize: 31200000
}
```

Comment: Have you checked [the docs](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/timing/properties/memory)?

Comment: @Bergi of course I have :-), although it explains what the metrics are . It doesn't state the measurements of these metrics (e.g. kb's or what else?)

Comment: My question is, what can I use the data for. What is their usage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What information can I obtain from the performance.memory object in Chrome?

The property names should be pretty descriptive.

> What do these numbers mean? (are they in kb's or characters)

The [docs](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/timing/properties/memory) state:

> The values are quantized as to not expose private information to
>   attackers.
>
> See the [WebKit Patch](https://bugs.webkit.org/attachment.cgi?id=154876&action=prettypatch) for how the quantized values are exposed. The
>   tests in particular help explain how it works.

> What can I learn from these numbers?

You can identify problems with memory management. See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/memory/effectivemanagement/ for how the `performance.memory` API was used in gmail.

Answer (score 3):

The [related API documentation](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/timing/properties/memory) does not say, but my read judging by the numbers you shared and what I see on my machine is that the values are in bytes.

A quick review of the code to which Bergi linked - regarding the values being quantized - seems to support this - e.g. *`float sizeOfNextBucket = 10000000.0; // First bucket size is roughly 10M.`*.

The quantized `MemoryInfo` properties are mostly useful for monitoring vs. determining the precise impact of operations on memory.  A comment in the aforementioned linked code explains this well I think:

```
86 // We quantize the sizes to make it more difficult for an attacker to see precise
87 // impact of operations on memory. The values are used for performance tuning,
88 // and hence don't need to be as refined when the value is large, so we threshold
89 // at a list of exponentially separated buckets.
```

Basically the values get less precise as they get bigger but are still sufficiently precise for monitoring memory usage.