# Chrome usedJSHeapSize property

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, memory-leaks

First of all, I've looked around the internet and found it quite badly documented.
Somewhere in my code I have a big memory leak that I'm trying to track and after using:

```
window.performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize
```

it looks like the value remains at the same level of 10MB, which is not true because when we compare to the values either visible here:

```
chrome://memory-internals/
```

or if we look at the Timeline in devTools we can see a big difference. Does anyone encountered a similar issue? Do I need to manually update these values (to run a command "update", "measure" etc?)

Following this topic:
[Information heap size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238574/information-heap-size)
it looks like this value is increased by a certain step, can we somehow see what is it or modify it? In my case from what I can see now the page has about 10MB, 30 minutes later there will be about 400MB, and half an hour after the page will crash.. 
Any ideas guys?

(Why the code is leaking it's a different issue, please treat this one as I was trying to use this variable to create some kind of test).

Comment: I have the same problem and don't know the reason. I resorted to referring to Task Manager for accurate memory usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a section of the WebPlatform.org docs that explains this:

> The values are quantized as to not expose private information to attackers. If Chrome is run with the flag `--enable-precise-memory-info` the values are not quantized.

https://webplatform.github.io/docs/apis/timing/properties/memory/

So, by default, the number is not precise, and  it only updates every 20 minutes! This should explain why your number doesn't change. If you use the flag, the number will be precise and current.

The [WebKit commit message](https://bugs.webkit.org/attachment.cgi?id=154876&action=prettypatch) explains:

> This patch adds an option to expose quantized and rate-limited memory
> information to web pages.  Web pages can only learn new data every 20
> minutes, which helps mitigate attacks where the attacker compares two
> readings to extract side-channel information.  The patch also only
> reports 100 distinct memory values, which (combined with the rate
> limits) makes it difficult for attackers to learn about small changes in
> memory use.

Comment: https://webplatform.github.io/docs/wiki/apis/timing/properties/memory this link is obsolete now. can you update it with new link please?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54659933/3124288 - in some cases usedJSHeapSize is updated much more frequently now